# Past tense in a dedication (page) for a recently passed away family member

Tags: past-tense, dedications

My grandfather recently passed away, and I want to name him in my dedication page of my thesis. At my university, one should first hand in the thesis and after that defend it for your supervisor and second reader. That is why I wonder if the past tense is suitable:

> ''This thesis is dedicated to the memory of my beloved grandfather [name]. Although he was my greatest motivation in finishing this thesis the past few months, he was unable to see my graduation. This is for him.''

Any other comments are also welcome.

Comment: Our sincerest condolences, and congratulations on your graduation.

Comment: Is it the word "finishing" that you are concerned with?  Are you "presenting" the thesis or maybe you were "readying the thesis for presentation"?  Also, he was perhaps -inspiring- you or -making him proud-, was your motivation.  "Living up to his faith and pride in me motivated me throughout my efforts preparing this thesis for presentation' ?  But I'm known to use some poor grammar and might be wrong in that.  I think you get your point across regardless and +1 in the condolences and congratulations.

Comment: Your dedication is fine.  The tenses are correct.  Even if he didn't see you finish, he knew you would.

Comment: Thank you very much for your condolences and congratulations. Regarding the dedicarion: is "have been my greatest motivation in finishing this thesis the past few months, he was unable to see my graduation" maybe even more suitable since he also was my motivation  after the weeks he passed away? Or does this sentence not flow as fine as my original one?

Comment: It would be "....has been...."   I like your original better.  The fact that he motivated you even after he died is clear.

Comment: Oh yes, of course it is "has". I agree with you. I will stick with the original one. Thanks for the feedback :).

Comment: @ab2 That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  If you answer and leave a comment @ fabby, I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for the suggestion!  However, my comments don't meet the standards of this site for an answer, and they served their purpose by helping the OP.  I appreciate your generosity.